# react-native-modal crash on android

Tags: reactjs, react-native, modal-dialog, expo

I am using react-native-modal with expo for building pop up selection. It works find on IOS device but when I run with android. It is crashed.

How can I solve this problem?

**Edit**
This is my code

/////////// Header Component

import --------

const HeaderComponent = ({selectLanguageVisible}) => {
    return (
        
           
              
                Apps Glossary
              
              
                
                  
                }
                
              
            
        
    )
}

export default HeaderComponent;

import Modal from "react-native-modal";
    import HeaderComponent -----

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectLanguageVisible: false,
    }   
  }

    setLanguageModalVisible(visible) {
    this.setState({selectLanguageVisible: visible});
     }
    render(){
        retrun(
    <View>
        <Header 
          selectLanguageVisible={() => this.setLanguageModalVisible(true)}
        />
        <View style={styles.modalContent}>
          <Modal 
            isVisible={this.state.selectLanguageVisible}
            animationIn="slideInLeft"
            animationOut="slideOutRight"
            onError={console.warn}
           >
            <View style={styles.modalContent}>
              <View 
                style={{flex: 1, 
                  flexDirection: 'row', 
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  margin: 20
                }}>
                <Icon style={styles.menu} name='language' />
                <Text style={styles.menu}> Select Translation Langage </Text>
              </View>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onSelectENtoJP}>
                <Text style={styles.switchList}>
                  <Icon style={styles.menuItem} name='circle'/>
                  English to Japan
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
               <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onSelectJPtoEN}>
                <Text style={styles.switchList}> 
                  <Icon style={styles.menuItem} name='circle'/>
                  Japan to English
               </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <Button 
                onPress={() => this.setLanguageModalVisible(false)}
                style={styles.button}
                title="Close"
              >
              </Button>

            </View>
          </Modal>
        </View>
    </View>
       )}

 }
```

Comment: please provide error log?

Comment: how can I print error log as it showed only "Crashed Apps"

Comment: check the console, no one can help you here without error log.

Comment: I try to check on forum. It said that react-native-modal is not supported with Android, only IOS is working. 

Is this true?

If so, what can I do?

Comment: please share the code here to atleast get the idea what you have done.

Comment: i update my code

Comment: Still crashing :/ what is happening.